# Compiling statically linked netty-tcnative fails with mismatch against jni.h from JDK

Tags: java, c, openssl, java-native-interface, netty

The situation is that I'm attempting to compile [netty-tcnative library](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative) version 2.0.3.Final on a Windows 10 32-bit machine. I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] .\src\jnilib.c(360): error C2373: 'JNI_OnLoad': redefinition; different type modifiers [C:<redacted>\netty-tcnative\openssl-static\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include\jni.h(1945): note: see declaration of 'JNI_OnLoad'
[INFO] .\src\jnilib.c(423): error C2373: 'JNI_OnUnload': redefinition; different type modifiers [C:<redacted>\netty-tcnative\openssl-static\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include\jni.h(1948): note: see declaration of 'JNI_OnUnload'
```

I then compared the signature of `JNI_OnLoad` and `JNI_UnLoad` in `jnilib.c` from tcnative against the `jni.h` from the JDK.

jnilib.c

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
...
void JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
```

jni.h

```
/* Defined by native libraries. */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved);
```

I'm on Java 8 update 131 but I checked this header going back to Java 7 and it's defined the same way. It appears the tcnative project changed this file while implementing shading support in [issue 272](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/pull/272/commits/a1cbec86bcdab1c6b8abb351ef7cffd25b0e9b78).

I have tried modifying the `jnilib.c` to include the `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` macros but it is overwritten by the build process and regardless I would like to have a repeatable build that doesn't involve modifying source files. What am I doing wrong? The same build environment was able to build version 2.0.1.Final.

Comment: If jnilib.c is overwritten by the build process, then you must modify the code that generates it, so as to emit correct declarations.  Presumably, the current code generator was built for a system where both the `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` macros expand to nothing, whereas that is not the case on Windows.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is certainly an option. This same environment (it's on a VM) was capable of building the 2.0.1.Final version of this library. Therefore I feel something changed in the library and either I'm unaware of how I'm supposed to change my build process or the library maintainers have a bug. I'm not sure which it is and I'm hoping one of the maintainers chimes in.

Comment: The problem is inconsistency of the multiple declarations of your two functions.  One pair of declarations comes from the external JNI header, the other from generated source code.  Since the external header defines the signature and convention that the corresponding JNI implementation will expect, the *only* reasonable solution is to make the generated code consistent with the JNI header.  Perhaps there's any easier way to achieve that than hacking the code generator (check the docs), but if you're only interested in comments from the maintainers then go to a project-specific forum.

Comment: I sent out https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/pull/300 to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/pull/300 was merged and fixes the problem. This will be part of netty-tcnative 2.0.7.Final